# For an X dimensional array where X is greater than 1,is only the first dimension optional,rest are mandatory?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get my head around this but since I am new to C I just can't imagine how it will be at or beyond 3D arrays.I know we have to mention the size of static 1D arrays,but in 2D arrays,the first dimension is optional in a declaration as in:

```
int arr[][2]={{2,3},{4,8},{5,3}};
```

But what about X dimensional arrays?Are the following OK or is only the first dimension optional to be mentioned and rest necessary?

```
 int arr[][][2]= blah blah;
 int arr[][][][8]= blah blah;
```

I know that in the above case of the 2D array,the second dimension is necessary to perform pointer arithmetic using `arr`,but I can't imagine how things would or wouldn't work out for array whose dimension is greater than 2.

Comment: note that a[3][2] is the same as a[3*2+2]. it is simply convenience to write them as multidimensional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one can be left blank.  In order to know how to get to a particular value, it needs to be able to compute the offset of everything but the first value.

For example:

char array[][3]

The system knows to go three bytes (assuming 1-byte chars) * the first part of the array index + 1 for each part in the second.

char array[][2][3]

The system knows to go 6 bytes (2*3) bytes * the first part of the array index + 3 * the second part + 1 * the last part.

If the 2 weren't there, you couldn't figure out how far to offset based on the value of the first index.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more.I can see that pointer arithmetic is likely to fail otherwise,but some more details will help a lot.

Comment: Did you already see the updated answer and want more, or only saw the original response?

Comment: I had only seen the original :-)

Comment: is it starting to make sense?  It's basically because the first value is only used for determining the amount of memory to allocate, not in the offset calculations, whereas all subsequent values are required for offset calculations in addition to memory allocation.  And when you have an initializer, you don't even need the first value for memory allocation since it's implicit from the size of the initialization.